# How to display first child only with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

currently I'm receiving this

```
<root>
<event>bla</event>
</root>
```

What I want is only this

```
<event>bla</event>
```

My xsl looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="Number" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/root/event" />
<xsl:template match="/root/event[1]">
<xsl:copy-of select="current()" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't figure out how to access the first node without going over /root first. 
Pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XSLT should answer your question. It will give `event` elements that are first child of their parent node :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="event[1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `root` element is skipped by the `match="*"` template.

Another way to do this (more simple but less evolutive) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="root/event[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you are using the identity rule, it is good to know how to override it in order to achieve maximum flexibility**:

.1. Override that excludes an element but still processes all nodes in its sub-tree:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

.2. Override for an element that excludes it and any node from its sub-tree:

```
 <xsl:template match="event[position() > 1]"/>
```

**These two combined give us the complete wanted transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="event[position() > 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <event>bla1</event>
    <event>bla2</event>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<event>bla1</event>
```